# Is it possible to have two Gurus at once?

Tags: scripture, guru, shishya

Are there any scritptural references to such situation ? What is the recommended course of action if there is an official Guru and other spiritual master is in contact for some reasons?

Comment: Yes there can be a situation in which a person takes dikṣā in a Tāntrikī mantra from one person & Vaidika sannyāsa from another. Svāmī Nigamānanda Sarasvatī, who took initiation in Śakti mantras from the famed Tāntrika sādhu Bāmākhyāpā & later Vaidika sannyāsa from a Satchidānanda Sarasvatī. Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṃsa took Tāntrikī pūrṇabhiṣeka from a Yogeśvarī Bhairavī & Vaidika sannyāsa from a Totāpurī. Caitanya Mahāprabhu was initiated into the Tāntrika Kṛṣṇa mantra by a Isvarapurī & Vaidika sannyāsa from a Keśava Bharatī.

Comment: Even Madhva was initiated first into Vaidika sannyāsa by a Acyutaprajñā Tirtha & later into the Tāntrika Kṛṣṇa/Nārāyaṇa mantra by Vyasadeva.

Comment: Vidyāraṇya had more than one guru too, he had both Śaṅkarānanda & Vidyātīrtha as his gurus, the latter was his mukhyaguru. Even the ācārya who teaches on Veda and other śāstras in gurukula, is a guru. Apart from what has been shared by অনু, there is one more guru, who is one's guru from birth. That's kulaguru (kulapurohita). Nowadays, not all kulas have, but in olden times, that was the case. These kulagurus were responsible for performing the saṁskāras of children in the kula too. Vasiṣṭha was Rāma's kulaguru, and Garga was Kṛṣṇa's kulaguru.

Comment: Gargamuni performed Kṛṣṇa's nāmakaraṇa & upanayana saṁskāras. And later Sāndīpani was Kṛṣṇa's guru, who taught him śāstras. So, even Kṛṣṇa had two gurus (kulaguru + guru who taught him Veda, etc. śāstras). But usually kulaguru (in most cases) doesn't exactly perform the role of guru, and his role is majorly that of the purohita of the kula (he might perform a normative guru's role too, if say he gives dīkṣā in some mantra to some members of the kula). Therefore, he might not be named alongwith one's gurus.

Comment: @Bingming Govindānanda states in his commentary of the Prāyascittaviveka states that the person who teaches the Veda for a fee is called the Upādhyāya, the guru is the person who initiates into Gāyatrī. You are mixinggutu with upādhyāya.

Comment: I am referring to ācārya not upādhyāya @অনু There's difference b/w the two, and ācārya holds higher authority than upādhyāya, he deserves the title of guru, as per smṛtis too. 2.140-141 of Manusmṛti points the difference b/w an ācārya & upādhyāya. An example I gave above of Sāndīpani, who was Kṛṣṇa's ācārya, not upādhyāya. Furthermore, ācārya does teach Veda, etc. too.

Comment: related (if not a duplicate) -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23909/4732